# Bash "archivo.sh" error en if al extraer la salida de cat a una variable y compararla en if

Tags: bash, shell, condiciones

Al extraer la variable va todo correcto, pero no me la compara, alguna ayuda?

```
camMode= sudo cat data.txt;

echo "$camMode";

if [ "$camMode" == "True" ]; then

        echo Mode is true
fi


if [ "$camMode" == "False" ]; then
        echo Mode is false
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es simple, solo tienes que cambiar

> camMode= sudo cat data.txt;

por

> camMode=$(<  data.txt);

Por lo visto la salida de la consola no se puede determinar como string, pero al leer el documento de esta forma si lo permite.